# project doesnt run - netbeabs

Tags: java, netbeans, web-applications, server

i try to run my web project.
i really dont know what is the problem..

this is the result of 
apache Tomcat console on net beans:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.15"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.15\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.15\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.644 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.15
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.645 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Nov 2 2014 19:25:20 UTC
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.645 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.15.0
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.645 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.645 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.645 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.645 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JAVA_HOME:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\jre
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.645 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_65-b17
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.645 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.645 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.645 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.15
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.646 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|study-computer
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.646 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\conf\logging.properties
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.646 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.646 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.15\endorsed
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.646 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.646 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.15
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.646 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\temp
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.646 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CineForm\Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Roaming\npm;.
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.787 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8084"]
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.846 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.849 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.857 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.857 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 504 ms
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.878 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.878 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.15
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.886 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\chinesecheckers.xml
08-Feb-2016 11:35:54.926 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
08-Feb-2016 11:35:57.108 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
08-Feb-2016 11:35:57.180 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\chinesecheckers.xml has finished in 2,294 ms
08-Feb-2016 11:35:57.180 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\linkeride.xml
08-Feb-2016 11:35:57.183 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
08-Feb-2016 11:35:57.820 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.api.core.WebAppResourceConfig.init Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the Web app resource paths:
  /WEB-INF/lib
  /WEB-INF/classes
08-Feb-2016 11:35:58.053 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.logClasses Root resource classes found:
  class controllers.ProfileController
  class controllers.MainController
08-Feb-2016 11:35:58.053 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init No provider classes found.
08-Feb-2016 11:35:58.156 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
08-Feb-2016 11:35:58.732 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\linkeride.xml has finished in 1,552 ms
08-Feb-2016 11:35:58.732 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\manager.xml
08-Feb-2016 11:35:58.805 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
08-Feb-2016 11:35:58.811 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\manager.xml has finished in 79 ms
08-Feb-2016 11:35:58.811 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml
08-Feb-2016 11:35:58.889 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
08-Feb-2016 11:35:58.892 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml has finished in 81 ms
08-Feb-2016 11:35:58.892 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\upload.xml
08-Feb-2016 11:35:58.895 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
08-Feb-2016 11:35:58.897 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/upload]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1683)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@4900d9b0]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5004)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [C:\Users\Maor\Documents\NetBeansProjects\upload\build\web] is not valid
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 13 more

08-Feb-2016 11:35:58.898 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\upload.xml
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/upload]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1683)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

08-Feb-2016 11:35:58.899 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\upload.xml has finished in 6 ms
08-Feb-2016 11:35:58.899 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\upload2.xml
08-Feb-2016 11:35:58.901 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
08-Feb-2016 11:35:59.005 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
08-Feb-2016 11:35:59.008 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\upload2.xml has finished in 108 ms
08-Feb-2016 11:35:59.011 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8084"]
08-Feb-2016 11:35:59.027 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
08-Feb-2016 11:35:59.036 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 4179 ms
08-Feb-2016 11:35:59.870 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/linkeride]
08-Feb-2016 11:35:59.913 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\linkeride.xml
08-Feb-2016 11:35:59.915 WARNING [http-nio-8084-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
08-Feb-2016 11:36:00.482 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-1] com.sun.jersey.api.core.WebAppResourceConfig.init Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the Web app resource paths:
  /WEB-INF/lib
  /WEB-INF/classes
08-Feb-2016 11:36:00.670 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-1] com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.logClasses Root resource classes found:
  class controllers.MainController
  class controllers.ProfileController
08-Feb-2016 11:36:00.670 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-1] com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init No provider classes found.
08-Feb-2016 11:36:00.757 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-1] com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
08-Feb-2016 11:36:01.213 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\linkeride.xml has finished in 1,299 ms
08-Feb-2016 11:36:01.240 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-7] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/linkeride]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
08-Feb-2016 11:36:15.775 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/linkeride]
08-Feb-2016 12:01:24.353 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\linkeride.xml
08-Feb-2016 12:01:24.356 WARNING [http-nio-8084-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule.begin [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
08-Feb-2016 12:01:25.320 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-15] com.sun.jersey.api.core.WebAppResourceConfig.init Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the Web app resource paths:
  /WEB-INF/lib
  /WEB-INF/classes
08-Feb-2016 12:01:25.494 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-15] com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.logClasses Root resource classes found:
  class controllers.ProfileController
  class controllers.MainController
08-Feb-2016 12:01:25.494 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-15] com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init No provider classes found.
08-Feb-2016 12:01:25.564 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-15] com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
08-Feb-2016 12:01:25.923 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of configuration descriptor C:\Users\Maor\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost\linkeride.xml has finished in 1,570 ms
08-Feb-2016 12:01:25.948 INFO [http-nio-8084-exec-16] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/linkeride]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
```

this is my web.xml file:

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    Archetype Created Web Application

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myrest1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>InitialTimerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>generalServlet.InitialTimerServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myrest1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

i try to open the project on the browser but cannot,
anynone know what can be the problem?

Comment: Please check the FAQ [ask] on how to ask good questions, so that you get good answers. At least please clean up the log output - that is completely unreadable as it is. Also, please add what you did and what does not work.

Comment: you don't say what you try to do, you say nothing about your configuration/setup/code, you say nothing about when exactly it goes wrong ... see where it becomes difficult to answer?

Comment: hi, i try to run the project... it worked yesterday and now it doesnt open the web... i dont have error on my java files... so i really dont know what happend.. anyone can explain me what is the problem?? why he project doesnt open on the internet when i click on run?

Comment: Google for *"IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified"*, there are already some question about this issue.